# How to move only windows 10 OS from my main HDD to a new SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

I recently bought myself a new 250 GB SSD because i only used to have 2 1TB HDD's on those two drives i have a lot of personal data like pictures and videos and important documents along with games, is it possible to clone only the Operating system i have on my C drive to my SSD and keep the data i have on my HDD's. I want to basicly start a fresh clean version of windows on the SSD and set that as a boot drive, i have no idea how to do that, if someone could give me software to allow me to move only the OS and tell me step by step on how to run it as a clean version of windows without any additional data/software on the SSD, sorry if this may sound stupid, but i never bought an SSD before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would say, dont try to clone anything, don't try to save the drive that your current os is installed on.  Copy the data that you want to keep on to the drive windows isn't currently using and then you can safely format the first drive with no data lose.  Then you can simply reinstall windows to the SSD, and present both 1tb drives to windows as normal storage.  That is by far the cleanest way to go.

If the above method just doesn't meet your needs, you should just be able to install the new SSD and then run the windows installer, selecting your new drive as the install point.  That will actually give you a clean install, vs trying to clone some parts of your old drive, but will leave the old windows installation on the old drive.  Once windows is installed on the new drive, you should be able to go in and clean up the old windows folder from the old drive and you will be good to go.

For the sake of being extra cautious, you could unhook your old drives while doing the windows install, this will ensure that the drives/data aren't affected by the installer.  If you go this way, you will probably need to make sure your BIOS boot order is correct to ensure that you are booting off the SSD, not the current windows disk.